# How to check port is up or down with SNMP

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, snmp4j

I develop a app which discovers a network topology and draw it programmaticly with java and SNMP4j
I send CDP and LLDP requests to devices and analyze result of this. However there are devices which has not support CDP or LLDP(like Access Point) therefor I cannot discover it. I must show it as unkown device.
Thanks to CDP and LLDP I know which device is on which port. To understand unknown device is on which port, 
I need a oid  to learn up and down ports of the Switch with SNMP  or another method.

I use SNMP4J

Comment: You need to look up the OIDs for the TCP Connection Table. A good SNMP browser will help you here.

Answer (score 1):

The table dot1dTpFdbTable (1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3) shows which MAC addresses can be reached on which ports.

Two things to watch out for: it is not supported by all devices and it does not only list the connected devices but also everything connected to those devices.

Comment: When I walk this oid, Cisco Switches does not repyl.